# Reference AppDbContext in class constructor of repository (where AppDbContext is not accessible)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, .net-7.0

In my solution I have 4 projects.

1. App.Web => A .NET 7 MVC project
2. App.Api => Another .NET 7 API project (both under the same solution)
3. App.Domain
4. App.Repository

For the moment (subject to change, depending on the answers) I have my context creation/definition and EF migrations in "Domain" layer.

App.Web (as well as App.API) needs to use that "common" DbContext (they both reference "Domain" which references "Repository".

I create/configure DI in program.cs (copied below), but my problem is I cannot access UsersDbContext from repository because it's in "Domain".

One solution could be creating another separate project called for example App.Data where only the context would be defined, and "Web", "Api" and "Repository" would reference that project to access the context, but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

This is my program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

#region swagger
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
  option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
  option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
  {
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = "Please enter a valid token",
    Name = "Authorization",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    Scheme = "Bearer"
  });
  option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
#endregion

#region jwt data
var validIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"];
var validAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"];
var issuerSigningKey = builder.Configuration["JWT:IssuerSigningKey"];
#endregion

if (validIssuer != null && validAudience != null && issuerSigningKey != null)
{
  #region jwt
  builder.Services
  .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  //.AddAuthentication(options =>
  //{
  //    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  //    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  //})
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
      ValidAudience = validAudience,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
              Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(issuerSigningKey)
          ),
    };
  });
  #endregion

  #region DbContext
  var connectionString = Util.getAppSettingsValue("ConnectionStrings:SurveyConnection");
  if (connectionString == null)
  {
    throw new Exception("SQL connection string is not set in appsettings.json!");
  }
  builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options =>
  {
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
  });
  #endregion

  #region neo4j data
  var neo4jServer = builder.Configuration["Neo4J:server"];
  var neo4jUser = builder.Configuration["Neo4J:user"];
  var neo4jPwd = builder.Configuration["Neo4J:pwd"];
  #endregion

  if (neo4jServer != null && neo4jUser != null && neo4jPwd != null)
  {
    #region neo4j
    var client = new BoltGraphClient(new Uri(neo4jServer), neo4jUser, neo4jPwd);
    client.ConnectAsync();
    #endregion

    #region services

    #region repository
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISurveysRepository, SurveysRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBlocksRepository, BlocksRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IQuestionsRepository, QuestionsRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOptionsRepository, OptionsRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAnswersRepository, AnswersRepository>();
    #endregion

    #region domain
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISurveysDomain, SurveysDomain>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBlocksDomain, BlocksDomain>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IQuestionsDomain, QuestionsDomain>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOptionsDomain, OptionsDomain>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAnswersDomain, AnswersDomain>();
    #endregion

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGraphClient>(client);

    builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
    builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenService, TokenService>();
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    #endregion

    #region users
    builder.Services
            .AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options =>
            {
              options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
              options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
              options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
              options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
              options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
              options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
              options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsersDbContext>();
    #endregion

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    //{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    //}

    #region swagger default page in release mode
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
      app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
      {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Surveys Web API");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
      });
      app.UseHsts();
    }
    #endregion

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception("Neo4J is not configured!");
  }
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("JWT is not configured!");
}
```

Questions.cs

```
public class QuestionsRepository : IQuestionsRepository
{
  private readonly UsersDbContext _context;
  public QuestionsRepository(UsersDbContext context) //=> cannot access UsersDbContext
  {
    _context = context;
  }
  ...
}
```

Any help on how to deal with this?

Comment: A DbContext is already a *multi*-entity Repository and disconnected Unit-Of-Work. It's not a database connection or model. You can have as many DbContext classes in your application as needed, eg to handle different use cases/scenarios.

Comment: `I cannot access UsersDbContext from repository because it's in "Domain".` that means the split between `Domain` and `Repository` is wrong. The `IQuestionsRepository` is definitely wrong, if it attempts to put a low-level data access interface on top of the high-level ORM object

Comment: I have CRUD operation code with EF. This might help you.
https://github.com/vishalspawar25/DotnetAPIWithDBUsingDocker/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I didn't get you.What do you mean?

Comment: OK, now that I've seen all the code, what's that supposed to show? It's not CRUD. It's nothing more than a cut-down example of the docs, except the call to the internal `RelationalDatabaseCreator` which is never needed in application code. It has nothing to do with this question

Comment: thats made for docker to pass environment variable to connect with sql container. My point is to show how dbcontext is used as DI, Other code is out of scope for  above question.

Comment: The root of this problem is following some sample code without understanding how or even if it works. This is solved by actually understanding the concepts. In this particular case the "repositories" and a lot of the DI code should be eliminated. `.AddSingleton(new UsersDbContext(connectionString));` is a critical bug that breaks EF's transactions. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, that's why it's scoped. It tracks all changes and persists all of them in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. To discard them, just `Dispose` it. That's why `AddDbContext` registers it as Scoped

Comment: I'm not an expert in siftware architecture, but trying to do my best. My collegue and me created this project from scratch. He created the App.Web and I created the App.Api and the Domain and Repo, then all was put under the same .Net Solution. I don't get why some of you say my approach is wrong, maybe I'm not being clear. We are just trying to have one common "place" for the AppDbContext.

Comment: Ok @Panagiotis Kanavos, I've replaced builder.Services.AddSingleton(new UsersDbContext(connectionString)); by   builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(connectionString); }); that I know is the correct way of injecting the DbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can put the DbContext, along with its associated entities in an App.Data project.

The database entities are, and should be different from your domain entities.  The domain models should only have the data that they need to work in them.

For example, if you had a User entity in the database with the following properties:

```
public class User{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
    public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Your domain logic would be split up between things like needing the first and last name for display purposes, but wouldn't need the password, or ID in that case, or just need the username and password for logging in.  It wouldn't make sense to always pass around the full database entity.

Answer (score 0):

We ended doing slight changes to our current api architecture as follows:

1. Context was moved from “Domain” to “Repository”.
2. “Repo” interfaces were moved to “Domain” (which will be responsible to store not only entities, but all interfaces).
3. “Repo” references “Domain” so it can access interfaces to implement them.
4. “Domain” has no dependencies.
5. Api references “Repo” just for context injection (though I don't like this part of the approach, because I like "Api" and "Repo" to be completely decoupled, but for now it's the way it works).
6. “Application” project created and bussiness logic moved from “Domain” to “Application” (this is not relevant to the question).

This way "Api" has access to context (only for service creation, though), "Repo" has access -obviously- to context, because context it now belongs to repo and solution compiles and works just fine.

[image: ftq architecture]